# Dipole-dipole interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I am am just wondering how to read the well-known formula for the dipole-dipole interaction Hamiltonian.

$$ \mathcal{H} = \frac{\mu^2}{2} \sum_{ij} \frac{{\bf S}_i \cdot {\bf S}_j}{r^3_{ij}} - \frac{3({\bf S}_i \cdot {\bf r}_{ij}) ({\bf S}_j\cdot {\bf r}_{ij}) }{r^5_{ij}} $$

with $\mu = 2\mu_B$ for magnons. Here the Hamiltonian has the dimension $\left[\mathcal{H} \right] = J^2 T^{-2} m^{-3}$ but the dimension of the Hamiltonian should be energy. When I diagonalize the Hamiltonian in terms of single particle bosonic operators $a^{\dagger}_k, a_k$ with wave-vector $k$

$$\mathcal{H} = \sum_{k} \varepsilon_k a^{\dagger}_k a_k$$

I also find a wrong dimension for the energy dispersion. I want to calculate scattering rates $\Gamma$ using Fermi's golden rule
and compare them to experiments but I also get the dimension of my scattering rates wrong due to the "wrong" dimension of the Hamiltonian. Can someone help me fixing this dimension problem? I always just find the above mentioned formula for $\mathcal{H}$ in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

The dipole-dipole interaction is an interaction between magnetic moments of the dipoles. Here you have an interaction between spins. Have you thought about adding the gyromagnetic ratio as $\vec{m}= \gamma \vec{S}$? Maybe that solves the dimensionality.